# Is "dynamic comparator" available in C++

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I am looking for a "dynamic comparator" that gives comparison result depending on a run-time argument.

Here is a comparator that compares two integers according to their distances to an input argument x.

```
struct leq
{
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b, const int x) {
        return abs(a-x) <= abs(b-x);
    }
};
```

I hope to use it to implement the following insertion to an set containing an integer 2, that is,

```
mySet = {2}

mySet.insert(3, leq(5)) results: mySet = {3, 2} // argument x of leq is 5 and abs(3-5) < abs(2-5)

mySet.insert(3, leq(1)) results: mySet = {2, 3} // argument x of leq is 1 and abs(3-1) > abs(2-1)

Note: the argument x may change for each element to be inserted into mySet.
```

Is there any way to use only the standard container set and its member functions to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual problem when you write that?

Comment: Is `x` a fixed value for each instance of `std::set`? Or you want to change the value of `x` from time to time?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "stateful".

Comment: It is possible to specify a set that uses a comparator function with the same, fixed value of `x` for all members in the set. That is, the argument is specified at runtime, but the same `x` value is used for all inserted values in the set. This is not exactly as the pseudocode you showed, so I am holding off on my answer until you clarify if this is exactly what you want. Note that with `x` being 5, both "2" and "7" will compare equal, which is not clear to me is the expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the comparator of a C++ std::set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777827/is-it-possible-to-change-the-comparator-of-a-c-stdset)

Comment: To Nicky, I want to change x from time to time.

Comment: To Mehrdad, yes I guess "stateful" is more appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: To Sam, I want different values of x being used for different inserted values. abs(2-5) != abs(7-5).

Comment: I start to doubt if my requirement reasonable. Suppose mySet = {26}, mySet.insert(8, leq(9)) will result mySet={8, 26}, then mySet.insert(27, leq(25)) causes problems: 27 should be after 26 but before 8 which is not achievable.

Comment: @leo to address someone use `@` and type the name then press tab

Answer (score 4):

You can give your comparator a constructor to pass it values at run-time:

```
struct leq
{
    const int x;
    leq(int x): x(x) {} // constructor

    bool operator()(const int a, const int b) const {
        return abs(a-x) < abs(b-x);
    }
};

// ...

// construct a set with a comparator set to x = 5
std::set<int, leq> my_set(leq(5));
```

Comment: my_set.insert() will use 5 for all the elements to be inserted into it, which is not what I want (see my revised Note). Do I miss anything?

Comment: @leo It's not possible to order different elements according to different criteria. I also can't see why it would be desirable for a `std::set`. You would need a container that allows arbitrary ordering of elements such as a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Sets assume they are always sorted.  So their comparator cannot change behaviour safely, unless the change agrees with every existing element order in the set.

The most dynamic set is:

```
template<class T>
using dynamic_set = std::set<T, std::function<bool(T const&,T const&)>>;
```

Then:

```
auto leq(int x){
  return [x](int a, int b){
    return abs(a-x) < abs(b-x);
  };
}
```

Gives us `leq`.

```
dynamic_set<int> mySet( {2}, leq(5) );
mySet.insert(3);
```

vs

```
dynamic_set<int> mySet( {2}, leq(1) );
mySet.insert(3);
```

does what you want I believe.

Replace `auto` with a `std::function<bool(int const&, int const&)>` in C++11 in `leq`.

Comment: I want to be able to use different x for each element to be inserted to the same set. Your solution seems only allows using different x for different sets.

Comment: @leo my very first paragraph reads "Sets assume they are always sorted. So their comparator cannot change behaviour safely, unless the change agrees with every existing element order in the set."  What is not clear?